# Use USDA Food API to search by food name instead of foodID

Tags: python, pandas, api, usda-fooddata-central-api

I am using an API to access the USDA food database and pull some nutrient data for a particular food, do some calculations (with another function partially shown here). I would like to find a way to search by a food name rather than foodID. Then I'll add it to my flask app and figure out how to allow a user to input some text to search for that food item, select it, and then run the function on it. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


apiKey = '' 
foodID = '' 

def nutrient_API(apiKey, foodID):
    #calls get api and json load
    api_resp = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/' + foodID + '?api_key=' + apiKey).text)
    #only return nutrition information
    api_nutrients = api_resp['foodNutrients']
    #first entry is its description, foodID, and database entry type
    nutrientDict = {"FoodID": [api_resp['description'],foodID, api_resp['dataType']]}

    for items in api_nutrients:
        if 'amount' in items:
            #each entry includes nutrient name, nutrient id, amount, and its respective unit
            nutrientDict.update({(items['nutrient']['name']): [(items['nutrient']['id']),
                (items['amount']),(items['nutrient']['unitName'])]})
        #print(nutrientDict)
    return(nutrientDict)


def trypfunc(foodID):
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(nutrient_API(apiKey, foodID))
    tryp_g=(dataframe['Tryptophan'][1])
#does some more stuff
    return trypfunc

# I call the above function for one food at a time with the foodID
print("Sesame seeds: ")
trypfunc(foodID='170150')
```

Comment: Does this API have any documentation? The answer is most likely there

Comment: yeah, but I didn't get how to use it. it's a bit confusing for a beginner. the API example I posted I found on Github.

https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-spec/fdc_api.html#/FDC/getFoodsSearch

Answer (score 2):

Based on the API documentation (I don't have a key to test it), you can query by keyword using the endpoint:

**GET Method**

```
foodName = "Cheddar Cheese"
requests.get('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={}&query={}'.format(apiKey, foodName))
```

**POST Method**

```
data = {"query" : "Cheddar Cheese"}
requests.post('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={}'.format(apiKey), data=data)
```

I'd also recommend to use string formatting when you are making concatenation such as this one. It makes the code easier to read ;). Even better, it you are in python 3.6+, the F-string. (But this is a must have)

Source : https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html#bkmk-6

#### EDIT:

With basic stringg creation, it is:

```
url = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key='+apiKey+'&query='+foodName
```

With string formatting, it is:

```
url = 'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={}&query={}'.format(apiKey, foodName)
```

With f-string, it is:

```
url = f'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}&query={foodName}'
```

#### EDIT 2

This works for me

```
import requests
import json

def call_API(foodName, apiKey):
    url = f'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}&query={foodName}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.status_code)  # 200
    return r.json


def call_API_2(foodName, apiKey):
    data = {"query" : foodName}
    url = f'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}'
    r = requests.post(url, json=data)
    print(r.status_code)  # 200
    return r.json

ans = call_API_2("Cheddar cheese", "DEMO_KEY")
```

You can find also some information about string formatting on https://pyformat.info/ (you should avoid %s anymore, it is depreciated)

I hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by use F-string? I'm not very familiar with it and from the examples I looked at I couldn't tell how I would apply it.

Comment: I've made an update regarding string formatting even if it out of the scope of the question. If your question is solved, don't forget to accept it ;).

Comment: hmm I keep getting this error every way I try it (with and without json loads, with and without .text at the end, using each of your examples). you got it to work like that?

{'timestamp': '2020-06-15T21:19:51.420+0000', 'status': 500, 'error': 'Internal Server Error', 'message': 'all shards failed', 'path': '/portal-data/api/v1/foods/search'}

Comment: one question how do you put serving size in that?